# Always open draggable Bootstrap modal in its normal fixed position

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-modal

I have a Bootstrap modal which is draggable and opens in a set position. The issue I have is if the modal is moved to another position and closed
the next time the modal is opened, its position is the same as when it was close and not in its normal fixed position. The normal position is screen centre.

What do I need to add to make the modal always open in its fixed normal position very time?

Model

```
<div id="open_legend_modal" class="modal fade" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="false" style="z-index:112">
  <div class="modal-legend" modal-ku style=" max-height:85%;  margin-top: 60px; margin-bottom:50px;" modal-lg>
    <div class="modal-content-search">
      <div class="modal-header-help">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    <div class="modal-title-current-signage" id="HideTitle" style="cursor:move">Legend </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body-legend">
    <li class="RoomBooked">
      <div class="LegendActiveText">Room booked (Conference display only)</div>
    </li>
    <li class="LegendOffline">
      <div class="LegendOfflineText">Offline</div>
    </li>
    <li class="LegendOverride">
      <div class="LegendOverrideText">Override (Conference display only)</div>
    </li>
    <li class="LegendSignage">
      <div class="LegendSignageText">Signage</div>
    </li>
      </div>
      <div class="footer_search_buttons">
    <div id="foot-button-margin-help">
      <button id="CurrentHelpcancelform" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary-edit btn-xs" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Script

```
$(document).on('click','#open_legend', function(e){
   $('#open_legend_modal').modal('show');
   $('.modal-legend').draggable({
      "handle":".modal-header-help"
   });
});
```

Comment: The bootstrap modal is not draggable by default. Which library are you using to add the draggable functionality?

Comment: Hi Rory, the library is jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.js

Comment: You'll probably need to use Bootstraps modal hide callback to re-initialize draggable and reset position.

Comment: The jQueryUI draggable widget doesn't save position by default either. It's likely you have some code which is causing that behaviour which needs to be removed.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Hi, I will try and find the code that could be causing the issue. Thanks again for your time.